# Volttron, noSegmentationSupported for BACnet devices

Tags: python, volttron, bacnet

Hellow,

Hope you are doing great.

I am reading data from AHUs but while fetching the list of objects it gives an error:
segmentationNotSupported.
On sending WhoIsIAm (`bacnet_scan.py`), I get this response:

```
Device Address        = <RemoteStation 4100:9>
Device Id             = 409
maxAPDULengthAccepted = 206
segmentationSupported = noSegmentation
vendorID              = 17
```

The configurations for my client application (`grab_bacnet_config.py`) are:

```
[BACpypes]
objectName: Betelgeuse
address: myIP/24
objectIdentifier: 599
maxApduLengthAccepted: 206 
segmentationSupported: segmentedBoth
vendorIdentifier: 15
```

I changed the maxApduLengthAccepted to that of the remote device. Also tried to make it large enough for other devices. Read other issues tried debugging using the ReadProperty provided by bacpypes github repo.

```
python read.py --debug bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ConfigArgumentParser:__init__
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:__init__
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ConfigArgumentParser:update_os_env
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:update_os_env
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - settings: {'debug_file': '', 'debug': set([]), 'max_bytes': 1048576, 'color': False, 'backup_count': 5, 'route_aware': False}
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - os environment
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:parse_args
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ConfigArgumentParser:expand_args Namespace(buggers=False, color=None, debug=['bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM'], ini='BACpypes.ini', route_aware=None)
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging:    - config: <ConfigParser.ConfigParser instance at 0x7fa5066dc0>
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging:    - ini_obj: {'objectidentifier': '599', 'segmentationsupported': 'segmentedReceive', 'objectname': 'Betelgeuse', 'address': 'myIP/24', 'vendoridentifier': '15', 'maxapdulengthaccepted': '206'}
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:expand_args Namespace(buggers=False, color=None, debug=['bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM'], ini={'objectidentifier': '599', 'segmentationsupported': 'segmentedReceive', 'objectname': 'Betelgeuse', 'address': 'myIP/24', 'vendoridentifier': '15', 'maxapdulengthaccepted': '206'}, route_aware=None)
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - debug: ['bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM']
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - color not specified
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - route_aware not specified
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - args expanded
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:interpret_debugging Namespace(buggers=False, color=None, debug=['bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM'], ini={'objectidentifier': '599', 'segmentationsupported': 'segmentedReceive', 'objectname': 'Betelgeuse', 'address': 'myIP/24', 'vendoridentifier': '15', 'maxapdulengthaccepted': '206'}, route_aware=None)
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - settings: {'debug_file': '', 'debug': set(['bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM']), 'max_bytes': 1048576, 'ini': 'BACpypes.ini', 'color': False, 'backup_count': 5, 'route_aware': False}
DEBUG:bacpypes.consolelogging.ArgumentParser:    - interpreted debugging
> read 4100:9 device:409 objectList 
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:__init__ <bacpypes.appservice.StateMachineAccessPoint object at 0x7fa50736d0> <Address 4100:9>
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:indication <bacpypes.apdu.ConfirmedRequestPDU(12,1) instance at 0x7fa5073ed0>
    <bacpypes.apdu.ConfirmedRequestPDU(12,1) instance at 0x7fa5073ed0>
        pduDestination = <Address 4100:9>
        pduExpectingReply = 1
        pduNetworkPriority = 0
        apduType = 0
        apduService = 12
        apduInvokeID = 1
        pduData = x'0c.02.00.10.71.19.4c'
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:    - segment size: 206
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:    - invoke ID: 1
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:    - segment count: 1
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:set_state 2 (AWAIT_CONFIRMATION) timer=3000
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:request <bacpypes.apdu.ConfirmedRequestPDU(12,1) instance at 0x7fa50733d0>
    <bacpypes.apdu.ConfirmedRequestPDU(12,1) instance at 0x7fa50733d0>
        pduDestination = <Address 4100:9>
        pduExpectingReply = 1
        pduNetworkPriority = 0
        apduType = 0
        apduSeg = False
        apduMor = False
        apduSA = True
        apduMaxSegs = 4
        apduMaxResp = 2
        apduService = 12
        apduInvokeID = 1
        pduData = x'0c.02.00.10.71.19.4c'
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:confirmation <bacpypes.apdu.AbortPDU(None,1) instance at 0x7fa51ab650>
    <bacpypes.apdu.AbortPDU(None,1) instance at 0x7fa51ab650>
        pduSource = <RemoteStation 4100:9>
        pduDestination = <Address myIP>
        pduExpectingReply = False
        pduNetworkPriority = 0
        apduType = 7
        apduSrv = True
        apduInvokeID = 1
        apduAbortRejectReason = 4
        pduData = x''
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:await_confirmation <bacpypes.apdu.AbortPDU(None,1) instance at 0x7fa51ab650>
    <bacpypes.apdu.AbortPDU(None,1) instance at 0x7fa51ab650>
        pduSource = <RemoteStation 4100:9>
        pduDestination = <Address myIP>
        pduExpectingReply = False
        pduNetworkPriority = 0
        apduType = 7
        apduSrv = True
        apduInvokeID = 1
        apduAbortRejectReason = 4
        pduData = x''
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:    - server aborted
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:set_state 7 (ABORTED) timer=0
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:    - remove from active transactions
DEBUG:bacpypes.appservice.ClientSSM:response <bacpypes.apdu.AbortPDU(None,1) instance at 0x7fa51ab650>
    <bacpypes.apdu.AbortPDU(None,1) instance at 0x7fa51ab650>
        pduSource = <RemoteStation 4100:9>
        pduDestination = <Address myIP>
        pduExpectingReply = False
        pduNetworkPriority = 0
        apduType = 7
        apduSrv = True
        apduInvokeID = 1
        apduAbortRejectReason = 4
        pduData = x''
segmentationNotSupported
```

Also tried to make APDU length large enough and equal to that of remote device but still couldn't read objectList. I am able  to read individual properties and their values but not overall list of objects. Can I read it?
I need to put them in @volttron for [grab_bacnet_config.py](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/main/scripts/bacnet/grab_bacnet_config.py)  script. Is there a way around to tweak the apdu length or segmentation stuff?

Regards,
Muhammad Anas Raza

Comment: The BACnet Device object List property can be read similar to an array. Read the array element 0 to get the object list count, then read element 1 to get the first object in the list. 

Its common for devices to not support segmentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because your client can (supposedly) support segmentation for "Both" directions - transmit & receive, the server/device/AHU doesn't.

So in order to read the full object-list, you have to fallback to looping thru the Object-List array - one element at a time.

Element/array-index 0 of the array (- the first element), contains the count of the number of data elements; for each element that you want to read - including the first one/element, you have to specify the target/desired element/index that you wish to read.